# nagiosgraph installation error

Tags: linux, rhel-5, nagios

I'm trying to install nagiosgraph where my nagios system works perfectly fine.
Downloaded `nagiosgraph-1.5.0.tar.gz`, unpacked it and issued `./install.pl --check-prereq`
It gives me

```
checking required PERL modules
  Carp...1.04
  CGI...3.15
  Data::Dumper...2.121_08
  Digest::MD5...2.36
  File::Basename...2.74
  File::Find...1.10
  MIME::Base64...3.07
  POSIX...1.09
  RRDs... ***FAIL***
  Time::HiRes...1.9717
checking optional PERL modules
  GD...2.30
  Nagios::Config... ***FAIL***
checking nagios installation
  found nagios exectuable at /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios
  found nagios init script at /etc/init.d/nagios
checking web server installation
  found apache executable at /usr/sbin/httpd
  found apache init script at /etc/init.d/httpd

*** one or more problems were detected!
```

I verified nagios configuration `/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg` and gave me no errors

Answer (score 2):

Install the package `libnagios-object-perl` as well as package `librrds-perl`.

This is assuming you are running Debian.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CentOS, just follow these steps:

Install CPAN if you haven't installed it yet.

```
yum -y install perl-CPAN
```

The install the module with cpan

```
cpan Nagios::Config
```

Press yes when asking to install dependencies..

That's it you got the perl module.

```
# ./install.pl --check-prereq
checking required PERL modules
  Carp...1.11
  CGI...3.51
  Data::Dumper...2.124
  Digest::MD5...2.39
  File::Basename...2.77
  File::Find...1.14
  MIME::Base64...3.08
  POSIX...1.17
  RRDs...1.3008
  Time::HiRes...1.9721
checking optional PERL modules
  GD...2.44
  Nagios::Config...36
checking nagios installation
  found nagios exectuable at /usr/sbin/nagios
  found nagios init script at /etc/init.d/nagios
checking web server installation
  found apache executable at /usr/sbin/httpd
  found apache init script at /etc/init.d/httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is ;

Only installing 
yum install perl-Nagios-Object

Before:  Nagios::Config... ***FAIL***

after: Nagios::Config...36

good luck

Answer (score -1):

Got the same error, while doing the pre-check to install nagiosgraph ( ./install.pl --check-prereq )

```
/root/nagiosgraph/nagiosgraph-1.5.2 # ./install.pl --check-prereq
checking required PERL modules
  Carp...1.3301
  CGI...4.13
  Data::Dumper...2.124
  Digest::MD5...2.54
  File::Basename...2.77
  File::Find...1.14
  MIME::Base64...3.15
  POSIX...1.17
  RRDs...1.3008
  Time::HiRes...1.9721
checking optional PERL modules
  GD...2.44
  Nagios::Config... ***FAIL*** <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
checking nagios installation
  found nagios exectuable at /usr/sbin/nagios
  found nagios init script at /etc/init.d/nagios
checking web server installation
  found apache executable at /usr/sbin/httpd
  found apache init script at /etc/init.d/httpd
```

Even after installing all the pre-requisites I could find around the net:

```
yum install perl-rrdtool perl-GD
yum -y install perl-GD php-gd rrdtool-perl rrdtool-php rrdtool perl-CGI perl-Time-HiRes
yum install perl-Nagios-Plugin
```

Looking I got to this page: http://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=28276
But when followed their step to fix the error:

```
1) perl -MCPAN -e shell
2) install Nagios::Config
```

I got another error:

```
Checking prerequisites...
 - ERROR: Test::Exception is not installed
 - ERROR: List::Compare is not installed

ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to install the versions
of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Nagios-Object' version '0.21.20'
Could not read '/root/.cpan/build/Nagios-Object-0.21.20-BbpgLp/META.yml'. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
CPAN: Module::Build loaded ok (v0.35)
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----    DUNCS/Nagios-Object-0.21.20.tar.gz    ----
    Test::Exception [build_requires]
    List::Compare [build_requires]
Shall I follow them and prepend them to the queue of modules we are processing right now? [yes]
```

Here, I entered "yes" and then I got prompted for more dependencies down the road, to which I answered "yes" to all of them.

Finally got to:

```
Installing /usr/local/bin/statusdat_demo.pl
  DUNCS/Nagios-Object-0.21.20.tar.gz
  ./Build install  -- OK
Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state

cpan[2]> exit
Terminal does not support GetHistory.
Lockfile removed.
/root/nagiosgraph/nagiosgraph-1.5.2 # ./install.pl --check-prereq
checking required PERL modules
  Carp...1.3301
  CGI...4.13
  Data::Dumper...2.124
  Digest::MD5...2.54
  File::Basename...2.77
  File::Find...1.14
  MIME::Base64...3.15
  POSIX...1.17
  RRDs...1.3008
  Time::HiRes...1.9721
checking optional PERL modules
  GD...2.44
  Nagios::Config...36 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
checking nagios installation
  found nagios exectuable at /usr/sbin/nagios
  found nagios init script at /etc/init.d/nagios
checking web server installation
  found apache executable at /usr/sbin/httpd
  found apache init script at /etc/init.d/httpd
/root/nagiosgraph/nagiosgraph-1.5.2 #
```

So I'm good to continue installing nagiosgraph.
Hope it helps.